# Sum of Traces of all Permutations of a Matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, permutations, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

I have a problem that reduces to finding the sum of the traces of all possible row permutations of a large matrix. For example if we had a 3x3 matrix, the possible row orderings would be (1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1), where the numbers represent the original row numbers. I want to find the sum of the Traces over all possible orderings.

I could calculate them all but that would scale at N!, which is too computationally expensive. Is there a way to simplify the problem? Or to approximate the answer without performing each computation?

**Some extra information**

The matrix represents probabilities so that all rows and columns sum to 1. And I know that the Trace of the original matrix is the largest term in the sum. (If any of that helps). Also, what I am actually trying to do is maximise the sum with respect to a parameter, lambda, which is used in a function to calculate the elements in the matrix. So if you want to transform the sum using an increasing function and maximise/calculate that instead then that would work too.

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you want the sum of all $\sum_{P \,Permutation}\text{Tr}({PA})$ if that is the case then it should be a multiple of the sum of all entries of $A$. The answer here is for $A$ taken a permutation i guess and in your question $A$ is doubly stochastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I claim that the sum of all order $n$ permutations matrices is equal to the matrix whose entries are all equal to $(n-1)!$. This is because for each $1\le i \le n$ and $1\le j\le n$, the number of permutations for which $\pi(i)=j$ is $(n-1)!$.

Another way of writing this constant matrix is $(n-1)!\def\1{{\bf1}}\1\1^T$, where $\1$ is a column vector of all ones.

Therefore, letting $B$ be any fixed $n\times n$ matrix, and $A_\pi$ be the permutations matrix corresponding to $\pi$, then
\begin{align}
\sum_{\pi\in S_n}\mathrm{tr}(A_\pi B)
&=\mathrm{tr}\left(\left(\sum_{\pi}A_\pi\right)B\right)
\\&=\mathrm{tr}\big((n-1)!\1\1^TB\big)
\\&=(n-1)!\mathrm{tr}(\1^TB\1)
\end{align}
The last equality is the cyclic property of trace. Finally, $\mathrm{tr}(\1^TB\1)$ is the sum of the entries of $B$. Therefore, the sum of the traces of the permutations of a matrix is equal to $(n-1)!$ times the sum of the entries of that matrix.